# Why do I keep getting an error in my code?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm attempting my first VBA code and I keep getting a run time error at this specific place in my code:

```
lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

Here is the actual code:

```
Sub Test_loop()

' Testing loop for highlighting

Dim lastrow As Long
Dim datevar As String

lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow
    datevar = Format(ws.Cells(i, 2), "mm/dd")
    If ws.Cells(i, 3) = "Received" And datevar = "11/24" Then
        Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(rrr, ggg, bbb)
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

My goal is to go though the last cell of my row and find a cell with a specific date that has a cell to the right with a specific text. Then it would highlight the first cell in that row and loop on to the next row. I'm not too sure where I went wrong and why I am getting an error.

would appreciate the help

Comment: Is `ws` declared and set somewhere else in your code? It needs to be set to an actual worksheet before you can access any of its methods/properties

Comment: No I seem to have forgotten that. Sorry for the basic question, but how would I go about setting ws?

Comment: *I am getting an error* is not a problem description unless you tell us specifically what *error* you're getting. You have the error message right on your screen in front of you, but unfortunately we can't see that screen from here. Please be specific when asking, and provide the relevant details, which in this case is the **exact** error message you're getting. You're asking us to help you solve your problem,  and it's in your best interest to make it as easy as possible for us to provide that help.

Answer (score 2):

The code is producing an error because `ws` isn't set to any actual worksheet. Here's how to fix this:

- add `Option Explicit` as the first line in the module. This will let
  Excel catch any undeclared variables
- declare `ws` as a variable of
  type Worksheet using a `Dim` statement. Also add declarations any
  other variables that we use later - `i`, `rrr`, `ggg`, `bbb`
- make `ws` point to an actual worksheet using a `Set` statement

Putting this together gives us:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test_loop()

' Testing loop for highlighting

Dim lastrow As Long
Dim datevar As String
' These variables weren't declared in the original code
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim rrr As Integer
Dim ggg As Integer
Dim bbb As Integer

' ws needs to be set to an actual sheet - Sheet1 is used here
' but replace this with the name of the actual sheet you need
'
' ws will be set to the worksheet called Sheet1 in whichever
' workbook is active when the code runs - this might not be
' the same workbook that the code is stored in
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

' For consistency, need to qualify Rows.Count with
' a worksheet
lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow
    datevar = Format(ws.Cells(i, 2), "mm/dd")
    If ws.Cells(i, 3) = "Received" And datevar = "11/24" Then
        Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(rrr, ggg, bbb)
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```